# How to enable sysstat from shell script in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, dpkg

In Ubuntu, I can install `sysstat` using apt, e.g.

```
apt-get install sysstat
```

And then enable it via interactive prompt

```
dpkg-reconfigure sysstat
```

But I want automate the process using fully automated shell script, what command I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
apt-get install sysstat -y
echo 'ENABLED="true"' > /etc/default/sysstat
service sysstat restart
```

save as say: `/root/enSAR.sh`, make executable `chmod +x /root/enSAR.sh`, then run as root:

`~# sh /root/enSAR.sh`

Checked, if you are running Ubuntu, then that should work. Debian uses additional values in /etc/default/sysstat

Answer (score 1):

Service may be configured via `update-rc.d`

Cron job uses settings from /etc/default/sysstat, string `ENABLED="true"`